# Disable input on keydown in angular6?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular6

I am trying to set `attribute disable` to that input only on which keydown event occured and remaining input should not be disabled?

### abc.component.html

```
<input type="text" (keydown)="disableIt($event)"> // <-- If keydown occurs 
                                                   //here, disable it
<input type="text" (keydown)="disableIt($event)">
<input type="text" (keydown)="disableIt($event)">
```

### abc.component.ts

```
public disableIt(evt) {
   if (evt.keyCode === 13 || evt.keyCode === 9) {
       evt.target.tagName.disabled  = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: very weird......

Comment: @ epascarello , What is weird?

Comment: `this.evt` <--- `this` is wrong

Comment: Thanks, its a typo, edited it

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly? Really unclear. So they start to type and you disable it? What are you trying to block exactly? Why is it not read only from the start?

Comment: I want to disable that input on which keydown event occurs, not other input.

Comment: What is "others"? Other input elements? Other events?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182873/discussion-between-ahmad-mnzr-and-epascarello).

Comment: In the end it is: `evt.target.disabled  = true;` but makes little sense why you would do it.

Comment: Do you mean, evt.target.disabled = true; will set input attribute disabled, once keydown event and corresponding keycode matches. I want to disable the input  so that once keycode matches user could not write some text.

Comment: Did you try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You select the element incorrectly and you should use which instead of keyCode.

```js
function disableIt(event) {
  var which = event.which
  if (which===13 || which===9) {
    event.target.disabled = true
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeydown="disableIt(event)">
<input type="text" onkeydown="disableIt(event)">
<input type="text" onkeydown="disableIt(event)">
```

Comment: keycode working fine. event.target.disabled = true or event.target.readOnly= true works for me.

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
<input type="text" (keydown)="$event.preventDefault();">
```

Comment: It disables the key to be written.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this controller:

```
ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.inputDisabled = [];
    $scope.inputs = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < numInputs; i++) {
        $scope.inputDisabled.push(false);
        $scope.inputs.push(i);
    }
    $scope.disableInput(which) {
        for(let i = 0; i < numInputs; i++) {
            $scope.inputDisabled.push(false);
        }
        $scope.inputDisabled[which] = true;
    }
}
```

And then in HTML:

```
<input ng-repeat="i in inputs" ng-disabled="inputDisabled[i]" ng-keydown="disableInput(i)">
```